# Excel sheet, Add in suffix to duplicate name then resets if different code(column A)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column A - Column B - Column C
  123    -  apple   - apple
  123    -  apple   - apple(1)
  456    -  apple   - apple 
  456    -  apple   - apple(1)
  456    -  apple   - apple(2)
  456    -  apple   - apple(3)
```

How do I add in suffix to duplicate name in Column B but it sees for Column A too?

Column A is code
Column B is name 
Column C the formula

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)>1,B1&"("&COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)-1&")",B1)
```

Drag down...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT #2**

[image: Solution]

> The formula I used in the above screen-shot was a prototype. After giving a second thought I have come up the following simpler version.

Put the following formula in cell `C1` and drag it down:

```
=B1&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:A1=A1)*($B$1:B1=B1))-1,"(0);;")
```

> The logic is to use **SUMPRODUCT** function to count the unique code combination, then use **TEXT** function to format the suffix string using this format `"(0);;"`.